# Selection color disappears if listRowBackground changed

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

If I change the row background color, then the default grey selection when I tap on the row disappears.
Is it possible to bring it back? Or do I have to add a custom overlay/manually change the color of the row when selected?

The code I used for changing the background color is the following: `.listRowBackground(Color(.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))`

Comment: Same thing for me. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: @alex.bour, no sorry